# Clear setTimeout or reset function

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, settimeout

I have a timer function and I want to clear the timeouts or reset the function, cause every time I execute it, a new timeouts are created, so I recieve several counts.
My idea is to reset the count every time I execute the function. I only want a 1 instance of timer and get the correct count. If if execute several times the function I want to restart to 0.

Here is my code:

```
var timeouts = new Array();
var timer = null;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client)
{
    client.on("start", function (){
    console.log('Someone has pressed Start button',new Date().getTime());

        //try to kill all timeouts
        for (var timeout in timeouts) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        };

        if(this.timer == null) {
            this.timer = new timer(1000, function (data) {
                io.sockets.emit('timeupdate', data);
            })
        }else {
            this.timer = null;
    });
});


function timer(delay, callback)
{
    // self-reference
    var self = this;

    if (!(this instanceof timer)) {
        return new timer();
    }
    // attributes
    var counter = 0;
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    /**
     * Delayed running of the callback.
     */
    function delayed()
    {
        console.log(counter);
        callback(counter);
        counter ++;
        var diff = (new Date().getTime() - start) - counter * delay;
        var timeOut = setTimeout(delayed, delay - diff);
        timeouts.push(timeOut);
    }

    // start timer
    delayed();
    var timeout = setTimeout(delayed, delay);
    timeouts.push(timeout);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using `clearTimeout()` is the correct way. The problem is your `for`-loop. This might look like a classic `foreach`-loop, but it is not. You have to do:

```
for (var i=0; i< timeouts.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, also I don't like this personally:

```
for (var i in timeouts) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]); // note how the array is indexed using var i
}
```

This is a common JavaScript pitfall - the `for (x in y)`-loop actually iterates over the array's indices, not the values. It can also iterate over an object's properties. Try it out:

```
var a = [3, 2, 5, 8];

for (var i in a) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(a[i]);
}

var o = { test: 'hello', number: 1234 }; 
for (var x in o)
    console.log(x);
```